# Laravel 5: Database Migrations (Help!)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Some useful Information:

- Im running on OS X (El Capitan Beta)
- Im using XAMPP
- I've successfully installed Laravel 5 and I can confirm it works.

Here is my migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

My .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=TvzwP6TLLRWK4zXDGDeudPOZnvXxYENz

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=users
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

My database.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => 3306,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

When I run 'php artisan migrate' on the Terminal I get a

```
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

My database connection credintels are:
The host is: 'localhost'
db username is: 'root'
db password is: ''

I have no tables in my database, I want to run the migration to create the table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the ```APP_KEY``` field contains sensitive information or you use that database login for anything but localhost, it would be advised to change that information.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: No I haven't checked the file permissions - how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're connecting to **localhost**, PDO is trying to connect to database using UNIX socket file which doesn't exist. Replace **localhost** with **127.0.0.1** and it will connect to your database using TCP connection, which should fix the issue.